# OpenAI API: How do I migrate from text-davinci-003 to gpt-3.5-turbo in NodeJS?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, text-davinci-003

How do I migrate from `text-davinci-003` to `gpt-3.5-turbo`?

What I tried to do is the following:

Changing this...

```
model: "text-davinci-003"
```

...to this.

```
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo"
```

Also, changing this...

```
const API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";
```

...to this.

```
const API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
```

The Problem is that it does not work. The code I will be giving is the unmodified code, so that anyone can help me what to change.

Why I wanted this upgrade?
I was irritated by `text-davinci-003`'s completion. Like sending "Hello" gives me an entire letter not a greeting.

Live Sample (Via Github Pages):
https://thedoggybrad.github.io/chat/chatsystem

Github Repository:
https://github.com/thedoggybrad/chat/tree/main/chatsystem

Comment: Script.js link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedoggybrad/chat/main/chatsystem/script.js

Comment: HTML file link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedoggybrad/chat/main/chatsystem/index.html

Comment: It is hard to post it here. I can't post the codes here.

Comment: By "does not work", do you mean there's an error message? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model.

There are three main differences between the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) and the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API).

1. API endpoint

   - Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`
   - Chat Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`
2. The `prompt` parameter (Completions API) is replaced by the `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
3. Response access

   - Completions API: `response.choices[0].text.trim()`
   - Chat Completions API: `response.choices[0].message.content.trim()`

Try this:

```
const getChatResponse = async (incomingChatDiv) => {
    const API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"; /* Changed */
    const pElement = document.createElement("p");

    // Define the properties and data for the API request
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [{role: "user", content: `${userText}`}], /* Changed */
            max_tokens: 2048,
            temperature: 0.2,
            n: 1,
            stop: null
        })
    }

    // Send POST request to API, get response and set the reponse as paragraph element text
    try {
        const response = await (await fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)).json();
        pElement.textContent = response.choices[0].message.content.trim(); /* Changed */
    } catch (error) { // Add error class to the paragraph element and set error text
        pElement.classList.add("error");
        pElement.textContent = "Oops! Something went wrong while retrieving the response. Please try again.";
    }

    // Remove the typing animation, append the paragraph element and save the chats to local storage
    incomingChatDiv.querySelector(".typing-animation").remove();
    incomingChatDiv.querySelector(".chat-details").appendChild(pElement);
    localStorage.setItem("all-chats-thedoggybrad", chatContainer.innerHTML);
    chatContainer.scrollTo(0, chatContainer.scrollHeight);
}
```